# Multiple checkbox delete javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this code which `delete` from database rows.But it removes one by one when pressing `delete`, `checkbox` not working.I want to *multiple delete by checking checkbox.*

```
function confirmDelete(delUrl) {
        if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete")) {
            document.location = delUrl;
        }
    }

function check() {
            document.getElementById("myCheck").checked = true;
        }

        function uncheck() {
            document.getElementById("myCheck").checked = false;
        }
```

**HTML**

```
<a href="javascript:confirmDelete('?action=deleteurl&id=<?php echo $row[0]; ?>')">
    <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck[]">delete</td>
```

PHP

```
<?php
if($_GET['action'] == "deletelink" && !empty($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id'])) {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM books WHERE id='".intval($_GET['id']);

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array ($result) )
        unlink("/home/me/public_html/upload/image/{$row['image']}");
}
```

Comment: can you show your html?

Comment: I've added code in main!

Comment: do you want to delete multiple row by selecting and clicking delete button?

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is not for multiple delete

this should be html

```
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck[]" class="multicheck" name="<?php echo $row[0]; ?>" value="<?php echo $row[0]; ?>"><a href="javascript:confirmDelete('?action=deleteurl&id=<?php echo $row[0]; ?>')">delete</a></td>


<a href="javascript:confirmMultiDelete(this)">Multiple Delete</a></td>
```

and this should be javascript

```
function confirmMultiDelete() {
    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete")) {
    var str = [];
    $.each(".multicheck:checked",function(){
    str.push($(this).val());
    });

    ids = str.join(",");
        document.location = '?action=deleteurl&id='+ids;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is my approach.

You need some modification to do multiple delete as my approach.

- First you have to put value in `checkbox` so you can get its value to
  delete.
- Second you have to add another button or action to delete multiple
  record.

Your Code ( with Modification ):

**HTML + PHP CODE**

```
<a href="javascript:confirmDelete('?action=deleteurl&id=value="<?php echo $row[0]; ?>"')">delete
</a>
<input type="checkbox" class="delCheck" id="myCheck[]" value="<?php echo $row[0]; ?>">
</td>

<!-- This will generate html code like below -->
<!--
<td>
    <a href="javascript:confirmDelete('?action=deleteurl&id=1">delete</a>
        <input type="checkbox" class="delCheck" value="1" id="myCheck[]" class="delCheck">
    </td>
    <td><a href="javascript:confirmDelete('?action=deleteurl&id=2">delete</a>
        <input type="checkbox" class="delCheck" value="2" id="myCheck[]" class="delCheck">
    </td>
    <td><a href="javascript:confirmDelete('?action=deleteurl&id=3">delete</a>
        <input type="checkbox" class="delCheck" value="3" id="myCheck[]" class="delCheck">
    </td>
    <td><a href="javascript:confirmDelete('?action=deleteurl&id=4">delete</a>
        <input type="checkbox" class="delCheck" value="4" id="myCheck[]" class="delCheck">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="button" value="Delete" name="delete_value" id="delete_value" class="delCheck">
    </td>

-->

<!-- Multiple Delete Button -->
<input type="button" id="delete_value" name="delete_value" value="Delete" />
```

**Javascript + Jquery**

```
function confirmDelete(delUrl) {
    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete")) {
        document.location = delUrl;
    }
}

$( document ).ready(function() {            

    $("#delete_value").on("click", function (e){                    
        var ids = '';
        $('.delCheck:checked').each(function(i){           
            ids += $(this).val() + ','; 
        }); 
        // go to delete url with action delete_all_ur 
        confirmDelete('?action=delete_all_url&id='+ids)             
    });      
});
```

**PHP Delete Code:**

```
if( @$_GET['action'] == "delete_all_url" ) 
    {

        $all_ids = $_GET['id']; 
        // Remove trailing ',' from IDs 
        $all_ids = trim($all_ids, ",");
        // Temporary variable to check only integer value passes
        $tempId = str_replace(",", "", $all_ids);

        // Check id numeric or not 
        if ( is_numeric($tempId) ) {            
            $sql_query = "SELECT * FROM books WHERE id in (".intval($_GET['id'].")";
            $result = mysql_query($sql_query);
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array ($result) )
                unlink("/home/me/public_html/upload/image/{$row['image']}");            
        } else {
            //echo 'errors';
        }

    }
```